# Solving a linear Equation!

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the equation i.e. $4xy=x$ and I have its two solutions i.e. $x=x$ and $y=1/4$ and $x=0$ and then $y=1/4$. I am puzzled that whether it is a equation merely defining the line that is, $y=1/4$ or is something overlooked by me?

Comment: $x=0$, $y=215.12$ is another solution. There are others...

Comment: It is sloppy to say $x=x$ since in that case you never allowed for $x=0$. However you have solved the equation wrong.

Comment: The equation defines a pair of straight lines, $x=0$ and $y = \frac14$.

Comment: Your argument should be, "If $x\neq 0$ then I can cancel from both sides and get $4y = 1$, so that $y=\frac{1}{4}$ is a solution...otherwise $x=0$ so that $y$ can take any value."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$4xy = x \iff x(4y-1) = 0$$

So any $(x,y)$ satisfying either $x = 0$ or $4y-1 = 0$ satisfies your equation.